# View is entirely black after modally switching from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to switch from the [main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0TGU.jpg) view to the [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0WFR.jpg) view modally.

I use the following code in the main view controller to do this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:false];
    loginViewController *loginView = [[loginViewController alloc] init];
    loginView.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil]; 
  }
```

The main screen is displayed fine. However, when the switch happens, the resulting view is a plain black screen. Why is this happening?

Comment: I assume you're using storyboards and have linked the login view to the `loginViewController`?

Comment: Yes,  I have already done this

Comment: Class names should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your story board name"                                                      bundle: nil];
    loginViewController *loginView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"your story board identifier"];
    loginView.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That worked! Can you explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @SivaDotRender, by using alloc init to instantiate your controller, you're creating a new controller with a blank view, which is why it's black. You need to instantiate the one you made in the storyboard, which is what the code in this answer does.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you